# jquery ajax not returning data on success c# asp.net

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, ajax, json

I cant for the life of me figure out why my data being returned is empty.  In fiddler i see the json

```
d=[{"response":[{"h":"h1"},{"h":"h1"}] }]
```

in fiddler there is a 200 status on the row where i see the json, but no other rows after that one ( maybe its not returning? ).  This is the code i am using

```
$('.SomeLink').click(function () {
    var sfn = $('#ID1').val();
    var sfp = $('#ID2').val();
    var sfi = $('#ID3').val();
    var gid = $('#ID4').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        cache: false,
        url: '/AjaxHandler.aspx/GetNewHtml',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: "{'a':'" + sfn + "','b':'" + sfp + "','c':'" + gid + "','d':'" + sfi + "'}",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data.response[0].h); //acts like a syntax error/no alert box
            alert(data); // [object Object]
            alert(data.response); // undefined
            alert(data.response.count); //acts like a syntax error/no alert box
        },
        error: function (e) {
            alert("Error: " + e.responseText);
        }
    });
});
```

AjaxHandler.aspx

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod()]
public static string GetNewHtml(string a, string b, string c, string d)
{
    List<Samp> samp = new List<Samp>()
    {
        new Samp{h = "h1"},
        new Samp{h = "h1"}
    };
    return Serialize(new { response = samp });
}
private static string Serialize(object obj)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    return serializer.Serialize(obj);
}
```

Samp Class

```
public class Samp
{
    public string h = "";
}
```

This is my first time using jquery ajax with asp.net so im sure im missing something that is probably relatively simple.  Im using .Net 4.0 , jquery 1.7.1 , iis 7.5

Comment: Have you tried inspecting the object in chrome or firebug and seeing what is actually inside of the data object?

Comment: Try using FireFox (with FireBug) or Chrome and using `console.log(data)` in your success handler to push the object out to the debug console, which will give you a better idea of how it comes out.

Comment: in your `success: function (data) {` do a `console.log(data);` and see whats in your console.

Comment: in the firebug console under json i see this
"{"response":[{"h":"h1"},{"h":"h1"}]}"

Comment: Strong inclination says that `data` is actually your list ... but just a guess at this point ... and certainly not what i would expect since your serialized an anonymous object containing the list named `response`.

Comment: No, actually place a breakpoint in the javascript and inspect the `data` object. Or perform a `console.log(data)` and see what is inside it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try data.d for your return object:

```
alert(data.d);
```

Comment: ooooh I can't remember but it was a long time ago in asp.net where I was taught to grab the data because jQuery stored it by default in `data.d` ... but it remains to be seen at this point.

Comment: yeah, it got me a few times :)

Comment: Theres my data!!! Thank you thankyou, thats something i will not forgot, for a while at least ;)

Comment: @hijinxbassist You should still learn to use the developer tools - FireBug in Firefox, or the integrated ones in Chrome - to troubleshoot things like this.  FireBug and Chrome will both show a lot of information about the network traffic, and both support `console.log()` to push objects to the console.

Comment: @AaronS Great memory recall. Is that a behavior specific to previous versions of jquery libraries? Or is it by default, what ASP.Net web methods serialize to. Be curious to know who is the culprit.

Comment: I believe it's the asp.net serialization that does it. His fiddler response showed how it was being sent down as d=[{}], which is one way to tell what was going on.

Comment: @AaronS i was kinda confused as to what that 'd' was.. i actually assumed it stood for data and had nothing to do with the return (derp).  i saw the same thing in fiddler too long b4 i posted.  thanks for the help, ill keep a more vigilant eye on all my debugger tools.

Answer (score 0):

its tripping over the quotes around the property names.  try string indexes.
try

`data["response"][0]["h"]`

returns h1

Comment: Writing `data["response"]` in JavaScript is effectively identical to writing `data.response`.

Comment: just tested it, acts like a syntax error with no alert box.  The data.d worked.

Comment: ok sounds good.  I was going off of his comment where his results were {"response":[{"h":"h1"},{"h":"h1"}]}...
JSON.parse(thatString) worked for me...

Comment: yes that actually works beautify after parsing the result of data.d  Excellent addition to the answer +1, not sure where that -1 came from..